# Pushing iOS Facebook Auth Credentials to a Web View

Tags: ios

Is it possible / how do you pass the Facebook iOS sdk authentication credentials to a web view (for use in the PHP sdk).

The facebook app can do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Tried searching around and seeing if anyone had any thoughts on this.  Most of the SO posts are from 2009/2010/2011 (before iOS 4 and the new FB sdks).

The obvious solutions probably (I think) won't work: ie. Passing the authToken or trying to somehow set the session (as the php sdk has its own session structure).  

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript against a webview, as a way to set values into it using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21

Comment: So are you suggesting to set the session with this?

Comment: I am suggesting that you could pass the access_token to the webview. I don't know what you are doing enough to know if this is necessary, or a good idea, but this is how I would pass the token to the webview if that is where I needed it.

Comment: Yeah I am using the PHP sdk so I'm not sure if auth token is enough to authenticate with it - it sets variables in the session and uses those.  I guess I could just switch my web backend to graph API calls...